# Algorithm for display nodes of a particular node based on in-degree and out-degree

Tags: algorithms, graphs, directed-graphs

Suppose we have the following directed graph. When I click on - say - node $e$, it should make the in-pointing neighbors and out-pointing neighbors of node $e$ red, as shown in the below Expected Result. My purpose is that when I click on any node of a directed graph it should tell me what nodes it is influencing (out-degree) and what are nodes which influenced it (in-degree).
**I want to make an algorithm for it. I don't know how to make it**.

- Definition: For a directed graph $G=(V(G), E(G))$ and a vertex $x_1 \in V(G)$, the
  *Out-Degree* of $x_1$ refers to the number of arcs incident from $x_1$. That is, the number of arcs directed away from the vertex $x_1$. The
  *In-Degree* of $x_1$ refers to the number of arcs incident to $x_1$. That is, the number of arcs directed towards the vertex $x_1$.

From mathonline.wikidot.com:
[image: graph with in- and out-degree as lables]

Expected Result:

[image]

**I want to make mathematical modeling for following pseudo code:**

1. Click on node i (e in example).
2. look for in-degree relationship r and get nodes(node d in below example).
3. look for out-degree relationship r and get nodes (node b and f in example).
4. display the nodes visited    through relationship r including e (expected
   result graph).

Comment: performing BFS on the graph with some extra conditions added should serve your purpose I guess

Answer (score 0):

If you want to highlight the neighbors:

Use adjacency list representation, where each node has a list of all out-edges out of it, and a list of all in-edges into it.  Then given a node you can rapidly identify what to highlight.

If you want to highlight everything connected to that node (at any distance):

Use DFS to find the set of nodes that are reachable from it.

Comment: thank you. My purpose to show connected nodes as mentioned  in expected result

Answer (score 0):

Your solution will highly depend on how you represent your graph. If your graph representation is stored both in-neighbours and out-neighbours, then this is a trivial task. So I assume you have a standard adjacency list representation of each node $v$ followed by a list of each of the out-neighbours which $v$ points to. For example, your graph above would be represented as:

- $a: b, c, f$
- $b: c$
- $c: d$
- $d: e$
- $e: b, f$
- $f: $

This sort of graph data structure supports a function like

```
G.getNbrs(a)
```

which would return the out-neighbours of $a$.

For you to find the neighbours which point inward to a node, you will essentially have to check each other node:

```
event clickOnNode(v) {
    turnRed(G.getNbrs(v));
    for each node n of G:
        if (G.getNbrs(n).contains(v)) // that is: if v is in the nbrhd of n
             turnRed(n);
    turnRed(v);   // if you also want the clicked-on node to appear red(?)
}
```

Of course, if your graph is represented differently (like an adjacency matrix) then the algorithm would have to be adjusted accordingly.